# Копия рекурсии

Tags: c#, .net, рекурсия

Всем привет!

Есть рекурсивный метод. Допустим, создается третья копия метода. Могу ли я узнать, что хранится (например, значение переменной, которая меняется с каждым вызовом рекурсивного метода) во второй копии метода, находясь в третьей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, конечно. Все данные, нужные для работы метода, вам стоит передавать в метод в качестве аргументов.

Comment: А вот и можно! :-) Если передавать это "что-то" как ссылку в потомка. ;-)

Comment: @StixoTvorec: Это и есть «все данные, нужные для работы метода».

Comment: @VladD - да, можно и передачей, но это не всегда удобно, согласитесь. Плюс ссылки позволяют менять содержимое памяти...

Хотя Вы правы, конечно. Для этого есть параметры вызова.

Comment: @VladD & @StixoTvorec благодарю. Теперь осталось это дело реализовать. ;)